# I don't see menu in QGIS Print Layout for enabling atlas, or browsing through atlas pages

Tags: qgis, qgis-atlas

I am watching Klas Karlsson's tutorial on creating an atlas in QGIS ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgPOwm7GrIo)), from August 25 2018. Unfortunately he does not specify his QGIS version.

In the top of his Print Layout window he has a menu for enabling atlas and browsing through atlas pages. But I don't see those on my installation, which is QGIS 3.10.4.

Am I doing something wrong or do I simply have the wrong version?

**Screenshot from tutorial video:**

[image]

**Screenshot from my installation:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably because you've created a new Report (Project > New Report) and not a new Print Layout (Project > New Print Layout)

[image]

As far as I know atlases are not available in Reports.

Comment: You are right, that was the reason :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In your Print Layout, go to '*View*', then '*Toolbars*' and check '*Atlas Toolbar*'

This is avaible for me in 3.10.2 so it should be in 3.10.4 aswell

Comment: Thanks. But Atlas Toolbar is not there. And even with all Toolbars and Panels checked, the Preview Atlas buttons are not there. https://i.imgur.com/8kWpGBI.png